# SQL Construction Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

TABLE : ITEMS

```
---------------------------------------
Item_ID     Description
---------------------------------------
1           Vivel Satin Soap
2           Flake
3           Maggie
4           Mango Juice
---------------------------------------
```

```
TABLE : SALES
------------------------------------------------
Sale_ID     Sale_Date    Item_ID     Quantity
------------------------------------------------
1           15-Feb-14       1           2
2           16-Feb-14       1           1
3           16-Feb-14       2           1
4           17-Feb-14       3           1
5           18-Feb-14       1           1
6           18-Feb-14       2           2
------------------------------------------------
```

I'm having trouble in constructing SQL query as the way i wanted.... Here, i have two
tables in the database as shown above. The "ITEMS" table is for Items' Description Look-up 
and "SALES" table for Items' Sale Record Look-up. Now, my requirement is, i want to select a records
from both the tables to generate report (as shown in the following). Report should contain 
Items Description and its corresponding Sum of Quantity.

```
REPORT
------------------------------------------------------
Item_ID     Description         Total_Quantity
------------------------------------------------------
1           Vivel Satin Soap         4
2           Flake                    3 
3           Maggie                   1
4           Mango Juice         (SHOULD BE NULL HERE)
------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried following SQL query and some more to generate the report but had a logical error.... 
so, help me to construct better!

```
1)   SELECT I.Item_ID, I.Description, Sum(S.Quantity)
          FROM ITEMS I 
          INNER JOIN SALES S ON I.Item_ID = S.Item_ID
          ORDER BY I.Item_ID;

2)   Select I.Item_ID, I.Description, Sum(S.Quantity)
          From ITEMS I, SALES S
          Where S.Item_ID IN (Select Item_ID from ITEMS)
          Order by I.Item_ID;


3) etc..........
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
          SELECT I.Description, Sum(S.Quantity)
          FROM ITEMS I 
          LEFT JOIN SALES S ON I.Item_ID = S.Item_ID
          GROUP BY I.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Inner just try with Left Join...
And you need to use Group by Clause

```
  SELECT I.Item_ID, I.Description, Sum(S.Quantity)  -- It will return Null for Mango Juice 
  FROM ITEMS I 
  LEFT JOIN SALES S ON I.Item_ID = S.Item_ID
  Group By I.Item_ID, I.Description
  ORDER BY I.Item_ID;
```

OR:

```
  SELECT I.Item_ID, I.Description, CASE WHEN Sum(S.Quantity) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Sum(S.Quantity) END Quantity  -- It will return 0 for Mango Juice 
  FROM ITEMS I 
  LEFT JOIN SALES S ON I.Item_ID = S.Item_ID
  Group By I.Item_ID, I.Description
  ORDER BY I.Item_ID;
```